# Android: Can we get more code to execute after ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData() is fired?

Tags: android

Here's the setup:

```
    <application
        android:manageSpaceActivity="[packageName].ManageSpaceActivity"
        ...
    >

    <activity
        android:name="[packageName].ManageSpaceActivity"
    </activity>


    public class ManageSpaceActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //TODO: check if this dir exists
       ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
        //TODO: recreate dir
        }
    }
```

Seems like the app is forced to close and I won't be able to replace the dir. Any thoughts?

Comment: "This is equivalent to the user choosing to clear the app's data from within the device settings UI. "  Doing it from the settings UI definitely kills the app.  It may not be possible.